# Detect React Router Transition in ES6 Class

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to detect a route change caused by clicking on a `<Link>`, so that I can change the state of my component when the route changes. I've seen a lot of places suggest that you can use `router.addTransitionHook`, but I have a couple problems with this.

1. I can't find any real documentation for `addTransitionHook`, and it sounds like it [might have been replaced](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1911).
2. I can't figure out how to get access to the router. Supposedly it's available under `context.router` in the constructor. I've tried everything suggested [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1499) (i.e. `Component.contextTypes = { router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired }`) and I'm not getting anything except `undefined` for my `context.router`. Do I need to do something when I create the router in order for the components to have access to `context`?

There are a couple proposed solutions that involve mixins. The [Lifecycle Mixin](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle-mixin) provides access to `routerWillLeave`. That seems like what I want, but mixins aren't available in ES6 classes.

Maybe I should try defining `onEnter` when I create the router as described [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/964), but I'd rather not have to add any code to the router declaration. That doesn't seem like a good solution.

**tldr;** What's the best way to detect a React route change in an ES6 class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out how to use events to solve my problem, but I realized what I should be doing is using lifecycle methods instead. My route was `<Route name="routename" component={RouteApp} path="/routename/:urlKey" />`. What I really cared about was when the `urlKey` param changed, and when that happens, the props of your component will change. Thus, I was able to put the code inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

history.listenBefore is not supported in React Router V4. Instead use history.block for blocking transition. And `history.listen((location, action) => { // do something })` for listening to route transition . Check the docs here [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to use `listenBefore` function from [History](https://github.com/rackt/history) module.

So you could use it like:

```js
history.listenBefore((location) => {
  // ...
});
```

or if you need to transition asynchronously, then:

```js
history.listenBefore((location, callback) => {
  // ...
});
```

Check for more in the [Confirming Navigation](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/ConfirmingNavigation.md#confirming-navigation) docs.

Comment: Where are you supposed to put this in order to get the same functionality as the Lifecycle mixin? It needs to run inside the component. But putting this in component's constructor creates a new listenBefore callback every time the component is created.